# Delete files with wildcard in subfolder

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I'm on Windows 7
I have directory called e.g. dir1. It has a few subdirectories e.g. subd1, subd2 and etc. Each of this subd could have a file with extention .tmp e.g. "abc_test write.tmp"
My goal: get into directory dir1 and then delete all files with .tmp in subfolders.
I do:

```
set dir=\my_path\dir1
pushd %dir%
```

And here's the problem: next step I do:

```
del /s "*\*.tmp"
```

but got the error:
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
My question: how could I delete files with extention .tmp is subfolders using wildcard?
Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The DEL command in your example should be in this syntax:

- `DEL /Q /F /S "*.tmp"`

Essentially you don't need to try to wildcard any folder paths and the `/S` switch is used to **delete specified files from all subdirectories** from the directory you are in when you run the command and all the way down recursively from all beneath subfolders.

---

### Further Resources

- [DEL](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html)